# Javascript file or module scope only variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, scope

Correct me if am wrong the function `require()` imports the `.js` file somehow as copy past it in the current document so if the `var name` was both in two modules would the second override the first?

 and how can i define **file scope only variables**

 note that i want to define my variable outside any function in my `.js` file and not it be in the `global scope`

 what are the solutions, does using the keyword `var` affects the variable scope, what define the scope other than `function` in `javascript`, can `module` object be useful for defining private variables in one file

**module1.js**

```
var name = 'i am module 1' 

foo = () => console.log(name)

module.exports = foo
```

**module2.js**

```
var name = 'i am module 2' 

foo = () => console.log(name)

module.exports = foo
```

**main.js**

```
const module1 = require('./module1')
const module2 = require('./module2')

module1() // "i am module 1" or "i am module 2"?
module2() // "i am module 2"
```

Comment: `"i am module 1" or "i am module 2"?` so, which is it? it will only output one of those, what has your extensive testing shown you?

Comment: am a bit confused i used var keyword and not used it am stick now for using it cause that worked, i want to understand what defines the variable scope other than functions and how can i divide my project into separate files without worrying about polluting each other scopes

Answer (score 1):

In javascript when you load the `.js` file directly in the '.html' file then the variables declared outside of the function get registered on global scope. To prevent this kind of things people starts using `IIFE` functions and wrap the single file in the `IIFE`. But in modern `Javascript` you can use `modules` like we used in `Nodejs` and module loader to load those files. Now modern browser supports `ECMAScript modules` and you can directly use them.

Main benefits of using modules is that you don't have to use `IIFE` function to prevent the variable registered on global scope. Now Every variable declared in that file are private to that file only unless you export it.

For Example: 
module1.js

```
var name = 'my name';

function getName(){
    return name;
}

module.exports  = {
    getName
}
```

In the above example `name` is private to this file only you can't use it in another file unless you export it.

Comment: so `require()` respects the `modules.exports` then how can you define a global `var` in the module and still using `require()`, Do you have to exported to become in the global scope ?

Comment: In `Nodejs` we can add properties to `globals` and in `browsers` we can add properties to `window` object but it is not the best practice to pollute the `global scope`. If you want to use `properties` or `functions` from one file to the other then you should `export` from that file and `import/require` into the other in which you want to use.